# Using data from a range to automatically complete a table

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup, transfer

I am having difficulty trying to get the formula right for automatically completing a table after selecting an option from a drop down cell.

I have got the drop down menu working great, what I need to do now is use the text found within the cell to collect other information relating to that option from another sheet.

I have been toying around with the VLOOKUP function however it is just returning a value of NA#. Would anybody be able to help me find out what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcJ68.png)

[Datarange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzsZX.png)

Comment: What's the `Data` range?

Comment: Data range is from another worksheet, Added to post for example.

Comment: Trying to add item ID and cost from "Datarange" into "Formula" sheet

Comment: Have you bothered to consult the help about how VLookup works? Everything that you've done wrong will become obvious if you apply the correct syntax.

Comment: Yes I tried help and looking online, I feel like it should be working but for some reason it isnt.

Comment: Took me a while to get the formula right but I got the answer through Jeepeds link. Thanks for your help troops!